# Core Data custom migration policy with multiple targets

Tags: ios, core-data, mapping-model

If I want to use a custom migration policy for a given entity, I believe I have to prefix the class name by the product module name, as shown on the following image:

[image: Mapping Model Inspector]

**How can I manage to handle multiple targets?**

I tried using the following entry: `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).VisitToVisitPolicy` but this does not seem to work. I still have the possibility to duplicate the mapping model, one for each target, but that does not feel right.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem trying to share model files between app and test targets. Almost gave up and thought I'll have to use your duplicate hack, but thankfully found a sane way:

```
// Get mapping model
let mappingModel = NSMappingModel(from: [.main], 
                        forSourceModel: sourceModel, 
                      destinationModel: destinationModel)!

// Get migration policy class name that also includes the module name
let fullClassName = NSStringFromClass(NSEntityMigrationPolicySubclass.self)

// Set policy here (I have one policy per migration, so this works)
mappingModel.entityMappings.forEach { 
    $0.entityMigrationPolicyClassName = fullClassName 
}

// Migrate
let manager = NSMigrationManager(sourceModel: sourceModel, 
                            destinationModel: destinationModel)

try! manager.migrateStore(from: sourceURL, 
                    sourceType: NSSQLiteStoreType, 
                       options: nil, 
                          with: mappingModel, 
              toDestinationURL: destinationURL, 
               destinationType: NSSQLiteStoreType, 
            destinationOptions: nil)
```

Comment: can you please share where you put the above code?

Comment: Can you provide more context, such as where and how you use this code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution is similar to Alexander's and it should work with multiple migration policies (one per entity). You need to set `Custom Policy` to class name without any namespace and after obtaining mapping model I do this:

```
    mapping.entityMappings.forEach {
        if let entityMigrationPolicyClassName = $0.entityMigrationPolicyClassName,
            let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String {
            $0.entityMigrationPolicyClassName = "\(namespace).\(entityMigrationPolicyClassName)"
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please share where you put the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippets from the previous answers, here's a more complete example implementation. In order to do this it seems like you need to do a fully manual migration.

**Note:** I haven't gotten this to work with the `@FetchRequest` decorator, but it is working with a basic MVVM setup. The part of the migration where I force update to get around WAL issues was causing issues with entities being loaded twice. Running a fetch request directly on a managed object context seems to work fine.

```swift
import CoreData

struct DataLayer {
    static let shared = DataLayer()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    // The base directory for you app's documents
    private var documentsUrl: URL {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        
        if let url = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "your.group.here") {
            return url
        } else {
            // Falling back to the regular core data location.
            let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            return urls.first!
        }
    }

    // The SQLite data store
    private var dataStoreUrl: URL {
        return documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("YourDataStoreName")
    }

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YourDataStoreName")
        
        migrateIfNeeded()
        
        // Prevent Core Data from trying to automatically migrate
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = dataStoreUrl
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = false
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = false

        // Load the new store just like you normally would
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }

    func getItems() -> [Item] {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)]
        
        do {
            return try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        
        return []
    }

    /// Checks if the current data store is up to date and migrates to the newest version if needed
    func migrateIfNeeded() {
        // The managed object model we might need to migrate to
        let finalManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Incremental", withExtension: "momd")!)!
        
        // If the app hasn't ever been launched there might not be a data store at all
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataStoreUrl.path) {
            print("No store to check")
            return
        }

        // Get metadata from the source data store
        guard let sourceMetadata = try? NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.metadataForPersistentStore(type: .sqlite, at: dataStoreUrl) else {
            fatalError("Could not find metadata for current data store")
        }
        
        // If the current data store is compatable with the desired object model, no need to do anything
        let compatible = finalManagedObjectModel.isConfiguration(withName: nil, compatibleWithStoreMetadata: sourceMetadata)
        if compatible {
            print("compatible - skipping migration")
            return
        }
        
        // Get the object model of the current data store
        let sourceModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main], forStoreMetadata: sourceMetadata)!
        
        // Because iOS by default uses WAL to write new data to a SQLite database there's a chance not all data has been written to the
        // main SQLite file. The following will force iOS to write all lingering data to the main file before migrating.
        do {
            var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: sourceModel)

            let options = [NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode": "DELETE"]]
            let store = try persistentStoreCoordinator!.addPersistentStore(type: .sqlite, at: dataStoreUrl, options: options)
            try persistentStoreCoordinator!.remove(store)
            persistentStoreCoordinator = nil
        } catch let error {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
        
        // Search for a mapping model from the current store version to the target version
        // You could also attempt to infer a mapping model here
        guard let mappingModel = NSMappingModel(from: [Bundle.main], forSourceModel: sourceModel, destinationModel: finalManagedObjectModel) else {
            fatalError("Could not find mapping model")
        }
        
        // Fix the migration policies for the current target
        mappingModel.entityMappings.forEach {
            if let entityMigrationPolicyClassName = $0.entityMigrationPolicyClassName,
                let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String {
                $0.entityMigrationPolicyClassName = "\(namespace).\(entityMigrationPolicyClassName)"
            }
        }
        
        // Set up the migration manager and temporary data store
        let migrationManager = NSMigrationManager(sourceModel: sourceModel, destinationModel: finalManagedObjectModel)
        let tempDataStoreUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("TemporaryIncremental.sqlite")
        
        do {
            // Migrate the old data store into the temporary one
            try migrationManager.migrateStore(from: dataStoreUrl, type: .sqlite, options: nil, mapping: mappingModel, to: tempDataStoreUrl, type: .sqlite, options: nil)
            
            // Delete the old data store and move the temporary into the original spot
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: dataStoreUrl)
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempDataStoreUrl, to: dataStoreUrl)
        } catch let error {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```